# Perl: debugging interpreter failure?

Tags: perl, debugging

I have a problem in Perl that I believe is not from my code. I have this re-entrant subroutine:

```
sub foo
{
   my $depth = $_[0];
   my $input = $_[1];

   my $result = mymodule::do_calc($input);
   if ($result) { foo($depth+1,$result); }

   print "mark $depth\n";
}
```

The program works perfectly fine as is. However if I comment out the print line, the program goes into an infinite loop.

If I put a  break point before the foo call, I can see that $depth is taking the value of a hash reference. With the print line in place it does not.

Does anyone know where to go from here? I am guessing I am triggering some sort of interpretter bug?

Comment: As long as `$result` is true `foo` will call itself, so all depends on what your `module::do_calc` function does. If `do_calc` returns a true value all the time it will cause an infinite call of `foo` inside `foo` which after a while should end with an error because of the limited stack depth. Unfortunately you did not post the `do_calc` function, so one cannot predict what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a relation between $input and $depth somewhere else in the code.